# Write several list of lists in a csv columns in Python

Tags: python, list, variables, csv, for-loop

I have a list of lists and need to write each of its elements in csv columns.
Using the code below it outputs exactly what I want.

```
for row in izip_longest(*averages_, fillvalue = ['']):
    writer.writerow(row[0] + row[1])
```

a sample line of row[0]:

```
['0.000000', '0.000586', '0.005819', '0.011434', '0.052012', 0.000586118993]
```

**Question:**
How can I replace the part `(row[0] + row[1])` with a code with a variable in it so that it automatically adds any number of sub-lists `(row[i] + row[i+1] + row[i+2]...)` in the main list?

Comment: The items in row are lists?  Can you show an example of a *row* produced by izip_longest()?

Comment: @wwii, yes they're. please see the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If row is a list of lists, replace `(row[0] + row[1])` with

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(row))
```

or

```
[item for sublist in row for item in sublist]
```

You are *flattening* a lists of lists.  I picked both of those from https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/2823755

Comment: Many thanks. **flattening** was the key then! I believe `itertools` executes faster than `list comprehension`, right?

Comment: I didn't do any timing but that other SO post indicated that it was.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well what you want than the following should do the job :

```
writer.writerow(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, row))
```

This work over all elements of *row*. If you want to sum the first *count* elements you can try like that :

```
writer.writerow(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, row[:count - 1]))
```

Comment: Had not used `lambda` before! seems to be very handy. Thanks for that Andrei. I selected wwii's answer just for slightly less execution time, but yours also works like a charm.